# Mapping an NSArray of NSDate with RKObjectMapping

Tags: objective-c, restkit-0.20

Suppose I have this Json :

```
{ "arrayOfDates" : [ "7-28-2013", "7-29-2013", "7-30-2013"]}
```

And my object is :

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* dates;

@end
```

I tried to map the arrayOfDates with dates.

```
RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MyObject class]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"arrayOfDates" : @"dates"}];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
mapping.preferredDateFormatter = dateFormatter;
```

The mapping result was an array of NSString !
Is that a way to get an array of NSDate instead of NSString ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get RestKit to do it. Instead, iterate over `dates` in the completion block called by RestKit and use your formatter to convert the strings, then update `dates`.

RestKit usually translates the string to a date if the destination property is an `NSDate`, but in your case it's an array so RestKit doesn't know that it should be transformed.

Comment: Thank you Wain ! It's can be a new features in RestKit maybe !

Comment: Feel free to implement it and send a pull request or raise the item on the RestKit google group :-)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this answer trying to solve a similar problem. I found a way to get RestKit to do this using a custom RKValueTransformer.

```
    RKObjectMapping* objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MyObjectWithAnNSArrayProperty class]];

    RKAttributeMapping* datesAttributeMapping = [RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"arrayOfDates" toKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(myArrayOfDates))];
    datesAttributeMapping.valueTransformer = [RKBlockValueTransformer
    valueTransformerWithValidationBlock:^BOOL(__unsafe_unretained Class sourceClass, __unsafe_unretained Class destinationClass)
    {
        // We transform a `NSArray` into another `NSArray`
        return ([sourceClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSArray class]] &&
                [destinationClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSArray class]]);
    }
    transformationBlock:^BOOL(id inputValue, __autoreleasing id *outputValue, Class outputValueClass, NSError *__autoreleasing *error)
    {
        // Validate the input and output
        RKValueTransformerTestInputValueIsKindOfClass(inputValue, [NSArray class], error);
        RKValueTransformerTestOutputValueClassIsSubclassOfClass(outputValueClass, [NSArray class], error);

        NSArray* inputValueArray = inputValue;

        NSMutableArray* result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:inputValueArray.count];
        // Convert strings to dates
        for (NSString* inputDate in inputValueArray)
        {
            [result addObject:RKDateFromString(inputDate)];
        }
        // Get a non-mutable copy
        *outputValue = [result copy];
        return YES;
    }];
    [objectMapping addPropertyMapping:datesAttributeMapping];
```